# Dynamic Programming Knapsack select only Unique Items in R

Tags: r, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have this code that selects multiple items to put in a knapsack from a dataframe. I wanted that it only selects an item from the dataframe only once:-

```
knapsack_volume<-function(Data, W, Volume, full_K){

Data = Data

# Data must have the colums with names: item, value, weight and volume.
K<-list() # hightest values
K_item<-list() # itens that reach the hightest value
K<-rep(0,W+1) # The position '0'

K_item<-rep('',W+1) # The position '0'


# while(length(Data$item) != 1){
  for(w in 1:W){

    temp_w<-0
    temp_item<-''
    temp_value<-0

    for(i in 1:dim(Data)[1]){ # each row

      wi<-Data$weight[i] # item i
      vi<- Data$value[i]
      item<-Data$item[i]
      volume_i<-Data$volume[i]



      if(wi<=w & volume_i <= Volume){

        back<- full_K[[Volume-volume_i+1]][w-wi+1]
        temp_wi<-vi + back

        if(temp_w < temp_wi){

          temp_value<-temp_wi
          temp_w<-temp_wi
          temp_item <- item
        }   
      }

      # Data = Data[-i, ]

    }
    K[[w+1]]<-temp_value
    K_item[[w+1]]<-temp_item
  }

return(list(K=K,Item=K_item))
}
```

The DataFrame looks like:-

item value weight volume

A    40      4      8

B    80      8     12

C    20      4      6

D   100     10     14

E    65      8      8

F    60     10      5

G    70      5     12

H    45      5      7

I    60      6      6

J    60      4      8

You may reproduce the dataframe with:-

```
Data = data.frame(item = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), 
value = c(40, 80, 20, 100, 65, 60, 70, 45, 60, 60), weight = c(4, 8, 4, 10, 8, 
10, 5, 5, 6, 4), volume = c(8, 12, 6, 14, 8, 5, 12, 7, 6, 8))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about deleting the item from dataframe once you put it in your knapsack? However you need a guarantee that your knapsack can be completely filled with unique items.